# Set a list in a parameter for calling API from python

Tags: python, pandas, api

I have a list from dataframe like this:

```
prod_id = data["id"].tolist()
prod_id

['2',
 '4',
 '6',
 '8',
 '10',
 '12',
 '14',
 '16',
 '18',
 '20',
 '22',
```

And, I am calling a API with parameter id = 14

```
bx24.callMethod('crm.deal.productrows.get',
               id = 14)
```

How can I call the API for all id from my list (prod_id)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and skip the list creation. I also believe you will gain some speed if there are a lot of values.

The only downside is you will need to flip the order of the arguments, so if you don't control `bx24.callMethod`'s code you will need to wrap it.

```
def api_call(id, path):
    bx24.callMethod(path, id)

data['id'].apply(api_call, args=('crm.deal.productrows.get',))

# or with lambda
data['id'].apply(lambda id, path: bx24.callMethod(path, id), args=('crm.deal.productrows.get',))
```

If you do control `bx24.callMethod`'s code then all is required is (after changing its signature to `id, path`)

```
data['id'].apply(bx24.callMethod, args=('crm.deal.productrows.get',))
```

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace I got a error TypeError: callMethod() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @JulioMoyanoBasso I don't know what `bx24.callMethod` is, but if it is a method, make sure to create an instance first, for **example**, `b = bx24()` then use `b.callMethod`